# flip card causes fatal error in swift

Tags: swift, fatal-error

I am following [this card flipping tutorial](http://www.codingricky.com/flipping-cards-with-swift-and-uikit/) and instead of creating the `UIView` and the `UIImageViews` programmatically I have created these in my storyboard.
When I click the card, the animation kicks in and turns over to the front image, but when I click again, this creates a `fatal error`:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

I can not figure out why this error occurs.

Here is the code which is the transformation of the above mentioned tutorial:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var flashCardView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var backImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var frontImage: UIImageView!


var showingBack = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tapped"))
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1

        flashCardView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
        flashCardView.addSubview(backImage)
        view.addSubview(flashCardView)
    }

    func tapped() {
        if (showingBack) {
            UIView.transitionFromView(backImage, toView: frontImage, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
            showingBack = false
        } else {
            UIView.transitionFromView(frontImage, toView: backImage, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, completion: nil)  
            //here I get the error when flipping the card back to the back image
            showingBack = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You get this when force-unwrapping an Optional that contains nil. You have 3 IBOutlets where you're force unwrapping them with "!". These are probably not hooked up properly in IB. "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" is the most common Swift question on SO, so some searching will set you on the right path pretty quickly.

Comment: share the storyboard document outline, it will be helpful to understand the problem.

Comment: this is what my storyboard looks like: I dragged a UIView into the screen, 150x200, then two  UIImageViews with same dimensions, all horizontally and vertically centred. So, only one square is visible.

Comment: @Michael   following your comment about the IBOutlets I started the project all over again and made sure that all connections are in order. I am still getting the error when I want to flip back to the original position.

Comment: backImage and frontImage are both recognised in the first step where we flip over from one image to the other, so it is really the question where the optional value is that is nil when flipping back!?!

Comment: I believe that when you transition, the old image's reference count is decremented, and since they're declared as `weak` it is getting destroyed. Try removing the `weak` declarations, and it will probably work. Looking at the tutorial, they don't have `weak`.

Comment: yes, this worked, the error is gone, however, there is another mystery and that is that when I flip back to the backImage then the image moves to the top left corner.

Comment: @Michael    hi Michael, since your suggestion solved the fatal error I'd like to accept it as the answer to my question. I guess that the strong/weak issue will be helpful for others. Can you please make your comment into an   answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that when you transition, the old image's reference count is decremented, and since they're declared as weak it is getting destroyed. Try removing the weak declarations, and it will probably work. Looking at the tutorial, they don't have weak.